# Is there any way to remove save and cancel in lightning modal popup

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, lightning

Is there any way to remove save and cancel shown in the modal popup of lightning screen?.

[image: Save Button Remove]

How to Remove that disable Save button from lightning model popup?

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to know where the modal popup came from to provide you with more guidance. In case you are using a Quick Action with an Aura Component, you can achieve that by implementing the **force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
```

You can check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader/documentation

Answer (score 0):

If the modal popup is custom, you can look for the

```
<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
```

and inside of this class, there should be a type of button, either

`<lightning: button/>` OR `<button>`

with the specific values you are looking for. Comment or delete those, or delete the footer itself.